# Heroku push via HTTPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, https, heroku

I'm trying to perform

```
git push heroku master
```

But the PC i am working on has some ports blocked so i can not `push` via `git@heroku.com:projectname.git` remote.

How can i push via **HTTPS**? I know it is possible since i can clone, pull and push via HTTPS any projects.

I tried to manually change `git@heroku.com:projectname.git` to `https://git.heroku.com/projectname.git` with no success.

Comment: Heroku now has an unlisted beta feature allowing git over http: [http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-git](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-git)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All pushes to Heroku git are over SSH.  The only way you'll be able to push is over SSH and port 22.

Note that without SSH some of the other heroku tasks will be impossible also.

Comment: Heroku now has beta support for HTTP Git: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-git

Answer (score 0):

it is official now from heroku with https git push.
Just change the url in .git/config to 
https://git.heroku.com/projectname.git