# ssh: connect to host heroku.com port 22: Bad file number fatal: remote host hung up unexpectedly

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I ran the following command on Git Bash
$ git push heroku master

but it returned this error instead

ssh: connect to host heroku.com port 22: Bad file number fatal: remote host hung up unexpectedly.

I have searched for this answer on stack but no solution yet. I'm lost please help

Answer (score 1):

Same question was posted here: [Heroku push via HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428997/heroku-push-via-https)

Most probably. your port 22 (ssh) is blocked by firewall. As far as I know ssh is the only way you can push content to Heroku (no http, no https).